# Why is ObservableCollection<string> property returning null?

Tags: c#

I have some confusion as to why I cannot add items outside of a class to an public `ObservableCollection`.

So lets say I have a class as follows:

```
public class TestClass 
{
    ObservableCollection<ViewModel> test;
    public TestClass() 
    {
        test = CreateDS();     
    }
    protected ObservableCollection<ViewModel> CreateDataSource() 
    {
       ObservableCollection<ViewModel> vm = new ObservableCollection<ViewModel>();
        return vm;
    }
    public ObservableCollection<ViewModel> Data {get {return test; } }
    public ObservableCollection<String> hosts {get; set;}
    // also tried this way instead
    public ObservableCollection<String> hosts = new ObservableCollection<String>();
}
```

I have initialized, or so I thought, the class by doing the following:

```
 TestClass tc = new TestClass();
 tc.hosts.Add(Environment.MachineName);
 DataContext = tc;
```

Can some explain to me why the above example always returns `null` in the `ObservableCollection<String>` `hosts`

But if I do the following, using the `string[]` `hosts`, I can at least get values and not a `null` returned

```
public class TestClass 
{
    ObservableCollection<ViewModel> test;
    string[] hosts = new string[] 
    {
      "server1",
      "server2"
    };
    public TestClass() 
    {
        test = CreateDS();     
    }
    protected ObservableCollection<ViewModel> CreateDS() 
    {
       ObservableCollection<ViewModel> vm = new ObservableCollection<ViewModel>();
        return vm;
    }
    public ObservableCollection<ViewModel> Data {get {return test; } }
}
```

I need to access and populate the `hosts` `ObservableCollection` from a button event outside of the class. I am new to mvvm and classes.

Comment: Your second example doesn't even compile.

Comment: think it was due to trying to return res and not vm

Comment: "Can some explain to me why this isn't working" what isn't working? What error (if any) are you getting? And in what way is the second one "working"? Because you clearly can `.Add` to an array even if it wasn't private.

Comment: `hosts` is null because you never assigned it a value. But this alternative `public ObservableCollection<String> hosts = new ObservableCollection<String>();` that you said you tried should work because you have now assigned a value to `hosts`. Also, it's probably worth looking at a C# style guide and following the conventions there. It makes it easier for other people looking at your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you declare a member in a class, it will start with the default value for that type. Which, if it's a reference type, which collections are, it'll be `null`. So when you do this:

```
public ObservableCollection<String> hosts {get; set;}
```

`hosts` will be `null` when you instantiate the object. You can do either this:

```
public ObservableCollection<String> hosts = new ObservableCollection<String>();
```

Which should work (if it's not working for you, then you have something else going on), or you can create it in the constructor:

```
public TestClass() 
{
    test = CreateDS();   
    hosts = new ObservableCollection<string>();  
}
```

Or you can assign it when you instantiate the object:

```
TestClass tc = new TestClass();
tc.hosts = new ObservableCollection<string>();
tc.hosts.Add(Environment.MachineName);
```

Which solution works best for you depends on exactly how you intent to use the object.

Finally a note on style. Typically in C# public members are pascal cased. See for example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2dbyw72%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

This may seem like an irrelevant point, but following the style guides does make it a lot easier for other people looking at your code to grasp what you are doing quicker, which is great, if you are asking other programmers for help.

Comment: I agree with the style guide suggestion. It took me an extra minute to grok the code in its current form.