# ObservableCollection is Null when I try to add TextBlocks through XAML to a custom control

Tags: c#, wpf, generics, collections

In my WPF Project, i am trying to create an `ObservalbeCollection` dependency property inside a custom control. I am not sure if i am doing it the right way but i am using the below code :

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty MenuOptionsDependency = DependencyProperty.Register("MenuOptions", typeof(ObservableCollection<TextBlock>), typeof(DropDownButton));


public ObservableCollection<TextBlock> MenuOptions
 {
    get
    {
      return (ObservableCollection<TextBlock>)GetValue(MenuOptionsDependency);
    }
     set
    {
     SetValue(MenuOptionsDependency, value);
    }
 }
```

The problem arises when i try to add `TextBlock`s through XAML to this control as follows :

```
<local:CustomControl1 x:Name="cmm">
  <local:CustomControl1.MenuOptions>
   <TextBlock/>
  </local:CustomControl1.MenuOptions>
</local:CustomControl1>
```

This throws a design time error saying :

> Collection 'CustomControl1'.'MenuOptions' is null

After going through the accepted answer on [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28631295/why-is-observablecollectionstring-property-returning-null), i understand `ObservableCollection`, being a reference type, will be `null` as it will be default value. I read through the answer but i am still unclear/unsure on how to implement the solution in my situation.

I need to be able to add objects to the collection through XAML(and also through C#). I would really appreciate if someone points out where i am missing/what i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must never set the default value of a collection type dependency property to something else than `null`. When you assign a non-null default value by (static) property metadata, all instances of your control will use the same collection object.

Instead, set a default value in the control's constructor by `SetCurrentValue`:

```
public DropDownButton()
{
    SetCurrentValue(MenuOptionsDependency, new ObservableCollection<TextBlock>());
}
```

Besides that, there is a strict naming convention, according to which the dependency property identifier field must be named as the property with a `Property` suffix. So your `MenuOptionsDependency` should actually be named `MenuOptionsProperty`.

It's also unclear whether the property type really needs to be ObservableCollection. You don't seem to register a `CollectionChanged` event handler anywhere, which indicates that your control is not supposed to react on such changes.

Consider a property declaration like this:

```
public DropDownButton()
{
    SetCurrentValue(MenuOptionsProperty, new List<TextBlock>());
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty MenuOptionsProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(MenuOptions), typeof(IEnumerable<TextBlock>), typeof(DropDownButton));

public IEnumerable<TextBlock> MenuOptions
{
    get { return (IEnumerable<TextBlock>)GetValue(MenuOptionsProperty); }
    set { SetValue(MenuOptionsProperty, value); }
}
```

Comment: What would be the issue if i keep using the name `MenuOptionsDependency` ?

Comment: And why use `...Register(nameof(MenuOptions)` instead of `...Register("MenuOptions")`?

Comment: Also, there would be casting issues here as you are trying to return `List<T>` from within a property of type `ObservableCollection<T>`. Maybe you meant creating a property of `List<T>` ? In that case, i would add that i need an `ObservableCollection` not a List.

Comment: 1. Some WPF features (where a PropertyPath is used) may require it. It is a naming convention that may be used by the framework. No need to deviate from it. 2.  It's safer, i.e. no typo possible. 3. Fixed. Why do you need an ObservableCollection? In case you want to *assign* an ObservableCollection to the property, `IEnumerable<TextBlock>` would be an appropriate type.